# From 1D Array to 2D Array with abundances

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have an array with unsorted string entries and I would like to "convert" it to an 2D array which contains every entry from the old array and the abundances (count of each String occurrence) for that entry.

I have no idea how to accomplish that in Java and I'm not sure if it is a good way to do it because the array has 90k+ entries.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by an abundance for an entry in an array.

Comment: @JackManey Probably the count of each element.

Comment: why don't you use database for that much of data

Comment: Exactly what does abundance mean in this context?  I've dealt with arrays, sorting (and of course java) but abundance just means "a lot" to me.

Comment: @pwny - Possibly, but it's not at all clear to me what the OP meant.

Comment: @EdwinBuck - Maybe the OP just has a lot of arrays?

Comment: @EdwinBuck my 1D array contains multiples entries with the same String and I want to count them.

Comment: @Mirar - `HashMap` is your friend.

Comment: the 90k+ String are from a file or a database? Maybe it would be better to reduce them first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using a map:

```
 Map<String, Integer> counted = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

 for (String s : theOriginalArray) {
      Integer count = counted.get(s);
      if (count == null) {
           counted.put(s, 1);
      } else {
           counted.put(s, count + 1);
      }
 }
```

Comment: Instead of calling `get` on each array element, you should use `containsKey` to check if it exists in the map, and only call `get` to update the entry if it exists.

Comment: @arshajii `containsKey()` runs essentially the same code as `get()`, so that would mean twice the work

Comment: @kiheru `containsKey()` returns a boolean and `get()` returns an object

Comment: Just because they may be similar in `HashMap` doesn't mean they will be in all map implementations (what if the OP requires a `LinkedHashMap` instead?). It would be wiser to use `containsKey`.

Comment: @arshajii I can give you that. The particular code snippet uses HashMap though.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

I did it with List and Map, but you can easily convert an array to a list, and it's easier to work with.

```
public static Map<String, Integer> getUniqueStrings(List<String> rawData) {
    Map<String, Integer> uniques = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    for(String s : rawData) {
        if(uniques.containsKey(s)) {
            uniques.put(s, uniques.get(s) + 1);
        } else {
            uniques.put(s, 1);
        }
    }

    return uniques;
}
```

Of course, for 90K entries, it will take some time.

Answer (score 1):

Is this a student problem?  If not, you can use a canned solution like the one provided by Google Guava.

```
import com.google.common.collect.HashMultiSet;
import com.google.common.collect.MultiSet;
// ...
String[] stringArray = ...;
MultiSet<String> bag = HashMultiSet.create();
Collections.addAll(bag, stringArray);
int sos = bag.count("Stack Overflow");
```